# What's the point of defining something as dynamic when you don't need to define something as dynamic to with-redefs it?

Tags: clojure

It seems to me that `with-redefs` can do everything that `binding` to a dynamic symbol can do, only it doesn't have the limitation of needing the `^:dynamic` metadata.  So when should I use one over the other?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Aside from requiring the `^:dynamic` metadata, `binding` also creates bindings that are only visible in the current thread, whereas the bindings made by `with-redefs` are visible in all threads. So, `with-redefs` is a very blunt tool and has the potential to affect other code running in the same VM. I've never seen `with-redefs` used outside of test code, nor should it be (at least in my opinion).

I would summarize the difference between the two as thus:

- **binding** with **^:dynamic** allows you to introduce a little bit of dynamic behavior in a controlled fashion. It's a good way of defining extension points in an API that let callers far up the call chain change the behavior of your code without having to explicitly pass parameters all the way through the call stack (some of which might not even be their code).
- **with-redefs** is a free-for-all. It's useful in testing, e.g. for mocking out entire sub-systems when the function under test has lots of dependencies.

Declaring a var as `^:dynamic`, together with the convention of using earmuffs to name dynamic vars (e.g. `*my-dynamic-var*`), has the added bonus that it's a self-documenting way of advertising to callers that that part of your code can be modified dynamically.

In summary: prefer **^:dynamic** and **binding** when writing APIs and production code. Use **with-redefs** in testing, and as a last resort to dynamically alter the behavior of vars beyond your control that weren't declared `^:dynamic` (and then, use with caution).

Comment: Good answer.  I've seen that earmuff naming convention and I didn't understand what it meant.  Am I supposed to use that naming convention on functions that are dynamic too, or just on primitive values?

Comment: I've never seen earmuffs on a `defn` for a function in a public API. For a dynamically bound function, I'd do something along these lines: https://gist.github.com/alexhall/5286484

Comment: That makes sense.  Though when I look through the clj-http project, it doesn't do that.  It puts the dynamic on the defn.

Comment: Yeah, either way works. At some point it just becomes a matter of taste.