# Clojure: binding vs. with-redefs

Tags: clojure, dynamic-scope

clojure.core has the macros [bindings](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/binding) and [with-redefs](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-redefs). Looking at the docstrings and the examples on clojuredocs.org, they seem to do something very similar. What is the difference and which one should I use in which situations?

Comment: Also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15747774/whats-the-point-of-defining-something-as-dynamic-when-you-dont-need-to-define/15748334#15748334

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Clojure Vars can have thread-local bindings. `binding` uses these, while `with-redefs` actually alters the root binding (which is someting like the default value) of the var.

Another difference is that `binding` only works for `:dynamic` vars while `with-redefs` works for all vars.

Examples:

```
user=> (def ^:dynamic *a* 1)
#'user/*a*
user=> (binding [*a* 2] *a*)
2
user=> (with-redefs [*a* 2] *a*)
2
user=> (binding [*a* 2] (doto (Thread. (fn [] (println "*a* is " *a*))) (.start) (.join)))
*a* is  1
#<Thread Thread[Thread-2,5,]>
user=> (with-redefs [*a* 2] (doto (Thread. (fn [] (println "*a* is " *a*))) (.start) (.join)))
*a* is  2
#<Thread Thread[Thread-3,5,]>
```

You can use the (undocumented) `binding-conveyor-fn` to convey thread-local bindings into new threads:

```
user=> (binding [*a* 2] (doto (Thread. (#'clojure.core/binding-conveyor-fn (fn [] (println "*a* is " *a*)))) (.start) (.join)))
*a* is  2
#<Thread Thread[Thread-5,5,]>
```

Comment: All of which is why `with-redefs` is meant for use in tests (where you may want to reach in and stub out a function), which `binding` can be useful in production code as well.

Comment: @Peeja thanks, so in other words, `with-redefs` should never be used in multi-threaded contexts?

Comment: @opqdonut as of 2019 june, the Vars documentation has a [Binding conveyance](https://clojure.org/reference/vars#conveyance) section which highlights `future`, `send`, `send-off` and `pmap` as having the capabilities for binding conveyance — does it mean that `binding-conveyor-fn` is no longer needed?

Comment: @ErikKaplun, `binding-conveyor-fn` is not needed if you use the functions you mentioned. However, if you create threads with `(Thread. ...)`, you still need it.